# Conditional rendering doesn't work because variable isn't defined yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do conditional rendering to show an Edit and Delete button in my React app.

```
<div>
        {author_id === user_id &&
        <Container>
        <Row xs="2">
        <Col><Button color="primary" size="sm">Edit</Button></Col>
        <Col><Button color="danger" size="sm">Delete</Button></Col>
        </Row>
        </Container>
        }}
 </div>
```

I'm getting `'author_id' is not defined` and `'user_id' is not defined` because the `album_id` is getting data from my database in `componentDidMount()` and `user_id` getting data from a Context.Provider from another component.

```
componentDidMount() {
      const { match: { params} } = this.props;
      console.log('COMPONENT HAS MOUNTED');

      fetch(`http://localhost:8000/albums/${params.albumId}`)
        .then((response) =>
          response.json())
        .then((data) => {
              this.setState({ albums : data });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error " + error)
              })
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.albums[0]){
        let author_id = this.state.albums[0].author;
        }
        if(this.context.user){
        let user_id = this.context.user.sub;
      }

    Album.contextType = Auth0Context;
```

So what do I do to make this code work since these two variables don't have values right away?

Comment: Why do you want to show the buttons if you don't have the data yet? Which part isn't working and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want to know what to do to load these buttons when I get the data to those variables.

Comment: What is currently happening? Are the buttons rendering? And where are you rendering, you don't have them in your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if both `user_id` and `author_id` are true, then check if they are the same, and *then* render the buttons.

Something like this should do what you want:

```
render() {
    const user_id = this.context.user ? this.context.user.sub : null;
    const author_id = this.state.albums[0] ? this.state.albums[0].author : null;
    const shouldRenderButton = user_id && author_id && user_id === author_id;

    return (
        ...
        { shouldRenderButton && <div>...</div> }
        ...
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript to the rescue. Use `NaN` as default value. Compared with each number, the comparision returns `false`. Compare `NaN` with `NaN` is also false.

```js
NaN == 128; // false
NaN == 'mau'; // false
NaN == NaN; // false
```

So even if you have one value (like `user_id`) and not the other, it still results in false and therefore will not render your snippet.

But as  JMadelaine alse mentioned, it would be better to not render anything at all if you don't have any data yet (or render a Loading-Icon).

```
render() {
    if(!this.state.albums.length) {
        return <span>Loading</span>
    }

    //.. other rendering
    return <div>{/*...*/}</div>
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I need conditional rendering for the code if `author_id === user_id` than render: Where `author_id = this.state.albums[0].author` and `let user_id = this.context.user.sub` . Because I only want to display the buttons if this is true.